# Dúvida sobre componente de paginação do site

Tags: php, html

Pessoal estou criando um site e gostaria de saber como é o nome ou como procuro na net sobre aquela 'tipo paginação' que fica nos sites ex: *site > smarte phone > modelo*, Que vc pod clicar em qualquer um e te direcionar para a página escolhida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome do componente que você procura se chama **Breadcrumb**. Também conhecido como **Navegação estrutural**.

Navegação estrutural é uma técnica usada em interfaces de usuário para proporcionar-lhes um meio de localização dentro da estrutura de programas ou documentos. ([Fonte](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o_estrutural))

Exemplos de frameworks que possuem breadcrumb.

- [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/)
- [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/breadcrumbs.html)
- [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/breadcrumbs.html)
- [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/breadcrumb/)
- [UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/breadcrumb)
- [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/breadcrumb.html)

Comment: Vale lembrar que a tradução literal é "migalhas de pão", em alusão à fábula de João e Maria, que usaram migalhas de pão para marcar o caminho e conseguir voltar da floresta :-)

Comment: Nossa, ótimo incremento!

Comment: Perfeito #Diego!

Answer (score 1):

O nome é **breadcrumb**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**REFERÊNCIA:**

---

1. https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/bootstrap-components/breadcrumb/
2. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/
3. https://daemonite.github.io/material/docs/4.1/components/breadcrumb/
4. https://material-ui.com/pt/components/breadcrumbs/